# Return type of pyspark UDF that returns any JSON

Tags: python, json, scala, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I have a pyspark UDF which reads from a source and stores it into a column in spark dataframe. How to return json without schema from udf

```
import json
from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
from pyspark.sql import types as st

df.printSchema()

root
 |
 |- filename: string (nullable = false)


def read_data(filename):
    # read json file
    return json.loads(output)

read_data_schema = st.StringType()

read_data_udf = sf.udf(read_data, read_data_schema)

df = df.withColumn('output', read_data_udf('filename'))

df.printSchema()

root
 |
 |- filename: string (nullable = false)
 |- output: string (nullable = false)
```

Here, the UDF is returning string instead of JSON. How can I return a json from the udf (that can be reused on different files with different json schema)